# Process finished with exit code 132 when theano imports gpuarray

Tags: python, theano

I'm on macos 10.12.5 and pycharm. 
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (x86_64)
Theano 0.9.0

My code works well on Windows 10. But when I pull the codes on my mac and try to run it. It gives me the following error:

```
Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)
```

I try to set some breakpoints and discover when it goes into

```
theano.scan
```

it collapses at line

```
from theano import gpuarray
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Can you please add the traceback of your error?

Comment: i just run the codes, and there's no traceback. it just shows the single line which i've provided in the description.

Comment: Can you open a python shell and try the import line in and see if you get an error.

Comment: strange! when i import it in a python shell, there's no error. but when i import it in pycharm, i get the error. but if i directly run the code in a terminal, i get `Illegal instruction: 4`

Comment: Can you update the traceback from the pycharm error in your question?

Comment: but in pycharm, i do not see any traceback. there is only one line which is `Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144992/discussion-between-colwin-and-charlotte).